# Datadog Agent In docker: TLS Handshake failure: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, datadog

I am intending to use datadog agent to forward my logs generated by my application residing in a docker container. The datadog agent is able to process the logs, but it is not able to send the logs over to datadog.

Docker-Compose File -

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my_app
    container_name: app_container
    labels:
      com.datadoghq.ad.init_configs: '[{}]'
      com.datadoghq.ad.instances: '[{"host":"%%host%%", "port": "%%port%%"}]'
      com.datadoghq.ad.logs: '[{"type": "file", "path": "/mnt/log/datadog_my_app.log", "service": "my_app", "source": "python", "sourcecategory": "sourcecode"}]'
      com.datadoghq.tags.service: 'my_app'
    environment:
       - DD_AGENT_HOST=datadog-agent
    volumes:
      - /tmp/logs/:/mnt/log/
    restart: always

  datadog-agent:
    image: gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:7
    container_name: dd-agent
    restart: always
    links:
     - web
    environment:
      - DD_API_KEY=<API_KEY>
      - DD_SITE=us5.datadoghq.com
      - DD_HOSTNAME=my_app
      - DD_APM_ENABLED=true
      - DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true
      - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true
      - DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true
      - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_DOCKER_CONTAINER_FORCE_USE_FILE=true
      - DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE=image:gcr.io/datadoghq/agent*
      - DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_METRICS=image:gcr.io/datadoghq/agent*
      - DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_LOGS=image:gcr.io/datadoghq/agent*
      - DD_AC_INCLUDE=name:app_container
      - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro
      - /tmp/logs/:/mnt/log/:ro
```

Logs are being processed but the logsSent is always 0 -

```
==========
Logs Agent
==========
    Reliable: Sending compressed logs in HTTPS to agent-http-intake.logs.us5.datadoghq.com on port 443
    BytesSent: 818556
    EncodedBytesSent: 13542
    LogsProcessed: 222
    LogsSent: 0

  docker
  ------
    - Type: file
      Identifier: 77a47e6c4b5e89d00414ac38b1923c290bb69fe347cbcdc1739f80bf0e439dd5
      Path: /mnt/log/datadog_my_app.log
      Service: my_app
      Source: python
      Status: OK
      Inputs:
        /mnt/log/datadog_my_app.log  
      Bytes Read: 37207   
      Pipeline Latency:
        Average Latency (ms): 0
        24h Average Latency (ms): 0
        Peak Latency (ms): 0
        24h Peak Latency (ms): 0
```

Upon checking the process-agent.log, I found that the forwarder is not able to complete a TLS handshake -

```
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:10 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:30 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/default_forwarder.go:679 in func3) | timed out waiting for responses, received 0/1
2023-06-21 05:59:30 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:191 in process) | Too many errors for endpoint 'https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/container': retrying later
2023-06-21 05:59:35 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/transaction/transaction.go:109 in func4) | TLS Handshake failure: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
2023-06-21 05:59:35 UTC | PROCESS | ERROR | (comp/forwarder/defaultforwarder/worker.go:195 in process) | Error while processing transaction: error while sending transaction, rescheduling it: Post "https://process.us5.datadoghq.com/api/v1/discovery": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: Have you seen this issue? Isn't it related to your problem? https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/20076